# Find one-dimensional $P,Q$ such that $PQ = P \cap Q$ and $P,Q$ not coprime

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, affine-schemes

I am looking for an example of the following situation:

Let $R = k[x,y,z]$ be the polynomial ring in three indeterminates where $k$ is a field. I want to find two prime ideals $P$ and $Q$ of $R$ which satisfy

1. $R/P$ and $R/Q$ are Dedekind domains
2. at least one of $P$ and $Q$ is not principal ,
3. $P+Q \neq R$,
4. $P \cap Q = PQ$.

In geometrical terms: I would like to find two regular affine curves in $\mathbb{A}_k^3$ given by prime ideals from which at least one is not principal (Points 1. and 2.). Moreover, they should intersect in at least one point (This is point 3.) and the curve obtained from these two curves (the curve given by $R/PQ$) should be reduced (This is point 4.).

Comment: what about $(x,z)$ and $(y,z)$? EDIT: ignore this comment, I misread part (4) of the question.

Comment: Note that condition 1 implies condition 2 by Krull's principal ideal theorem.

Comment: @JefL Thanks for your comment. We may assume wlog that the components meet at the origin, i.e. both $P$ and $Q$ are contained in $(x,y,z)$. But then it seems to me that there is "not enough space" for condition 4. to hold. But I cannot make it rigorous.

Comment: do you assume $k$ to be algebraically closed? Because otherwise you can't necessarily assume this maximal ideal to be $(x,y,z)$ e.g. it could be something like $(x^2-2,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$.

Comment: @JefL I don't see why I assume that the residue field of $(x,y,z)$ is $k$. No, I don't assume $k$ to be algebraically closed. My archetypical ground field is finite.

Comment: @windsheaf I don't follow your last comment, if $x,y,$ and $z$ are indeterminates, then the residue field of $(x,y,z)$ is obviously $k$. Jef L's point is completely valid. Your curves won't necessarily intersect in any $k$-points, so you can't assume that their intersection contains the origin (which is clearly a $k$-point).

Comment: Also if $P$ or $Q$ were principal, they'd have [codimension at most one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem) and thus wouldn't be curves.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see Jef's comment, but I'll leave the comment above for the link.

Comment: @jgon Ah, I was missing that it might not be a $k$-point, you both are completely right about that!

Answer (score 0):

This can never happen. If such an example existed, localizing at a maximal ideal containing $P+Q$, the same holds and so assume that $R$ is a regular local ring of dimension three, $P,Q\subset R$ prime ideals with all your properties, 3) being automatic now. Then $R/P$ is a dvr, so let $z$ be generator of its maximal ideal. Since, $R/Q$ is also a dvr, $Q=(x,y)$ where they form a regular system of parameters in $R$.

First, assume that neither $x$ nor $y$ is zero in $R/P$. Then, $x=uz^m, y=vz^n$ in $R/P$ with $u,v$ units. We may assume without loss of generality $m\geq n\geq 1$. By abuse of notation, we call the lifts of $u,v,z$ to $R$ by the same letters. Notice that $u,v$ are units in $R$ and $z$ is a non-unit. Then, $x'=x-v^{-1}uz^{m-n}y$ goes to zero in $R/P$. Thus, $x'\in P\cap Q$. But, $x'$ is part of a regular system of parameter and thus can not be in $PQ$, the latter is contained in the square of the maximal ideal.

The case when $x$ or $y$ is zero in $R/P$ reduces to the above.